# Confusion in props and state in REACT js

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

Just have a simple question here. I have 2 classes now, class AExample and BExample. So now, im creating an instance of class BExample in the render section of class AExample. I have added this code in class A in the render section.

```
<BExample
state= {this.state}
/>
```

So in class BExample, when i try to

```
console.log(props);
```

In the props value, Im getting the values of state. The problem is Im confused now, whether it is the state of BExample or AExample? Do you guys the state value represents which class? If yes why is it so?

Comment: It is the state of AExample which you have passed to BExample as a prop.

Comment: Whatever object values you pass with the component become props for the component being rendered. While the state represents the local variables of a component. You should once go through the official documentation here. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: You are passing the state of AExample class to BExample class as a prop. And props have nothing to do with the state unless you make your state by using props.

So having a prop named as state is the reason you are being confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, The `state` of `AExample` is now get set as a prop named `state` to the `BExample` component.

Any prop to a component as an attribute is referred as a prop to the attached component in react.

So,

```
<BExample
state= {this.state}
/>
```

in the above example `{this.state}` is the state of the `AExample` but `state` is a prop of `BExample`. That is why when you log `props` it shows that state value of `AExample`.

Answer (score 1):

In ReactJS, the state of the parent component becomes the props of the child component.

So, in the `A` component you are passing the `'A's State'` to the `'B' component`.

For `B` it is now `props`. So, in `B` if you will `console.log(props)` you will get the value of `'A's State'`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html